# SSIS Developer expressions

Tags: sql, variables, ssis, expression, etl

I would like to create an SSIS variable using an expression in which I take a script I had in a stored procedure and use it in a variable. I would like to parse a file name and location into the script at run time hence I am doing it this way.

My code is below:

```
DECLARE @Cardholder VARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @Cardholder = BULKCOLUMN
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK' + @[User::CARDHOLDER] +', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON

SELECT DELIVERY_METHOD, CURRENCY_CODE, COUNTRY, MOBILE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, EMAIL, LAST_NAME, CREATE_DATE, FIRST_NAME, ID
FROM OPENJSON(@Cardholder, '$.CardHolder')


WITH(
    DELIVERY_METHOD varchar(255) '$.delivery_method',
    CURRENCY_CODE varchar(255) '$.currency_code',
    COUNTRY varchar(255) '$.country',
    MOBILE varchar(20) '$.mobile',
    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE datetime '$.last_modified_date',
    EMAIL   varchar(255) '$.email',
    LAST_NAME   varchar(255) '$.last_name',
    CREATE_DATE datetime '$.create_date',
    FIRST_NAME varchar(255) '$.first_name',
    ID  bigint  '$.id'
)
```

I am getting the below error:

> Expression cannot be evaluated

[image: SSIS error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a quotation issue, try using the following expression:

```
"DECLARE @Cardholder VARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @Cardholder = BULKCOLUMN
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'"  + @[User::CARDHOLDER] + "', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON

SELECT DELIVERY_METHOD, CURRENCY_CODE, COUNTRY, MOBILE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, EMAIL, LAST_NAME, CREATE_DATE, FIRST_NAME, ID
FROM OPENJSON(@Cardholder, '$.CardHolder')


WITH(
    DELIVERY_METHOD varchar(255) '$.delivery_method',
    CURRENCY_CODE varchar(255) '$.currency_code',
    COUNTRY varchar(255) '$.country',
    MOBILE varchar(20) '$.mobile',
    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE datetime '$.last_modified_date',
    EMAIL   varchar(255) '$.email',
    LAST_NAME   varchar(255) '$.last_name',
    CREATE_DATE datetime '$.create_date',
    FIRST_NAME varchar(255) '$.first_name',
    ID  bigint  '$.id'
)"
```

And make sure the variable's data type is `String`